# Python Pandas ExcelWriter, Error Values that disappear

Tags: python, excel

The attached code opens an Excel sheet, retrieves data, processes it and writes the results to another spreadsheet.
What is strange is that it works the first time, but the second time a problem appears. And I do not know how to fix the problem. Python does not give me any error.

The program sum the different total then write the number of articles sold according to the article.

The second time, we see that the TOTAL CB, Cash or Check values disappear and I do not understand why.

I run the code the first time:
[image: Print data]

I restart the code:
[image: second print data]

We see that the total values have disappeared.we see that the totals have disappeared. When I look at my sheet excel 1 we notice that the € have disappeared. This may be the origin of the problem. But I do not understand why the sign disappears.

Excel before the code : 
[image: excel original]

Excel after running : 
[image: after running]

And here the Excel file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LtDvot78Uh-e8MhiG1Ti-MLc05aXyGua/view?usp=sharing

A tip made a copy of the excel file

The goal is to be able to run the code several times without having this problem

thank you !!!!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
data=pd.read_excel("site.xlsx","Feuille1", keep_default_na=False, skiprows = [0,1]) 
print(data)

totalballon=[]
b=[]
espece=np.where(data['Unnamed: 2']=='TOTAL Espèces')[0]
carte=np.where(data['Unnamed: 2']=='TOTAL CB')[0]
cheque=np.where(data['Unnamed: 2']=='TOTAL Chèque')[0]

articles=["Ballon bleu", "CH24 jaune", "Ballon rouge", "Chapeau", "Ballon vert", "Pantalon", "Fleurs"]

print(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 4'][espece]))
print(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 4'][carte]))
print(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 4'][cheque]))

for i in articles:
    nb=np.where(data['Unnamed: 2']==i)[0]
    b.append(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 1'][nb]))
print(b)

ballon=["Ballon bleu", "Ballon rouge", "Ballon vert"]

for j in ballon:
    nb=np.where(data['Unnamed: 2']==j)[0]
    totalballon.append(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 1'][nb]))
totalballon=[sum(totalballon)]
print(totalballon)

with pd.ExcelWriter('site.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    writer.book = load_workbook('site.xlsx')

    TOTALespece = np.sum(data['Unnamed: 4'][espece])
    TOTALcarte = np.sum(data['Unnamed: 4'][carte])
    TOTALcheque = np.sum(data['Unnamed: 4'][cheque])

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'articles':articles})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'nombres':b})
    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Total ballon':totalballon})

    dfe = pd.DataFrame({'TOTAL Espèces':[TOTALespece]})
    dfcarte = pd.DataFrame({'TOTAL CB':[TOTALcarte]})
    dfcheque = pd.DataFrame({'TOTAL Chèque':[TOTALcheque]})

    df1.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=1)
    df3.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=2)
    dfe.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=3)
    dfcarte.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=4)
    dfcheque.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=5)
```